# AWS Elastic BeanStalk deploy err's with: The directory name is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS elastic beanstalk app.  During deployment I get the following error in the cfn-init.log

```
2020-07-16 23:55:11,069 [INFO] Running configSet Hook-PreAppDeploy
2020-07-16 23:55:11,085 [INFO] Running config Hook-PreAppDeploy
2020-07-16 23:55:11,335 [INFO] Command hooks succeeded
2020-07-16 23:55:11,351 [INFO] Running configSet Hook-EnactAppDeploy
2020-07-16 23:55:11,365 [INFO] Running config Hook-EnactAppDeploy
2020-07-16 23:55:18,897 [INFO] Command hooks succeeded
2020-07-16 23:55:18,928 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2020-07-16 23:55:18,928 [INFO] Running config postbuild_0_new_env_website
2020-07-16 23:55:19,413 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2020-07-16 23:55:19,413 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 129, in build
...
```

I can't figure out what code is being executed... I can find a cnf-init.exe, which doesn't help because it's binary, and I can't find a construction.pyc on the instance, even though likely it wouldn't help.

Without a name of the directory that it is trying to use I don't know where next to look to fix the issue.  Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

EDIT: based on comments I have done some more digging... I looked into the cloud formation template that ELB creates, and I found the following...

`"Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild": [],`

But that appears to have nothing in it... so the not sure it is actually doing anything.  That said, this appears to confirm that it is something AWS generates because the cloud formation template is the first place postbuild shows up.  And there are a bunch of other hooks defined there that aren't in the version package.

Comment: What is postbuild_0_new_env_website.?

Comment: I don't know.  The last part "new_env_website" is the name of the application.  There are a bunch more config files with different names above it as well being run.  Some have the app name in them, other don't.  I think they are generated by aws as I didn't create them.  I tried searching the file space on the instance for it and found nothing, so I am not even sure where it is running.  I will add a few more lines above for context...

Comment: `postbuild_0_new_env_website` seems as something in your .ebextensions.

Comment: It also seem as you are trying to run [eb plaform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html).

Comment: I checked the ebextensions early on.  There isn't much there... just some cert installation stuff.  Basically one short file and a pfx file.  I didn't write them, but they make no mention of postbuild or any hooks.  I double checked the zip that got uploaded to... nothing got added by magic, and no files with the word PreApp in the name in the whole zip.  So AWS must be creating those things as part of it's deploy process.  Which is the thing I wish I could see deeper into.  Like the cfn-init.exe.  If I could see the source for that I might have a place to look at least.

Comment: Have you search for `postbuild_0_new_env_website`. This is not a EB term, to my knowlage. I think its comming from somewhere of your app.

Comment: The name new_env_website is the name of the elastic beanstalk application... so the app I am deploying has never heard that name and it couldn't be in the uploaded zip.  I did search for postbuild_0*...  nothing.

Comment: I see. Does your app create any files in ` /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/`? Wonder what could cause `postbuild` to fail and what folder is invalid.

Comment: It's windows... so the path is different.  But there are some hooks... none called postbuild though.  And none of the hooks that are there are in the uploaded package.  But they do sorta match some of the things in the log... like for Hook-EnactAppDeploy there is C:\Program Files\Amazon\ElasticBeanstalk\hooks\appdeploy\enact    But nothing has the name build at all

Comment: I think it might actually be the extensions.  I found a resume_db.json file that had  "postbuild_0_new_env_website" in it... and described the commands from the extensions.  It looks like aws magically generated this and that is runs the commands in a container.  One of the commands reference the pfx file that is also in ebxtensions, and I am guessing that wouldn't be accessible inside the container.  But still just guessing...  more googling to do. :)

Comment: okay, it is just called container_commands, not sure it has anything to do with containers like docker.  So it still seems like something in the extension must be the cause... but there really isn't much there.  And it clearly has access to the paths it is using.

Comment: `container_commands` is not related to docker. It has commands then run when your application is in staging folder. Do you know which commands fail?

Comment: I don't. I tried putting output statements but none came out.  Kinda thinking it isn't the commands but whatever it runs to run the commands at this point... I even added a new command to run first that was just an output command... and nothing but the error.